# 'Model Form' has no attribute cleaned_data

Tags: django

I want to send an email for a confirmation in order to change his user's password.

I have a classic problem in Django and the server returns this error :

**'Model Form' has no attribute cleaned_data**

```
def forgottenPwdEmail(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordResetRequestForm(request.POST)
        if User.objects.filter(email = form.cleaned_data['email']).exists() and form.is_valid():
            user = form.cleaned_data['email']
            sendResetPasswordMail(user, request.META['HTTP_HOST'])
            return redirect('passwordConfirmation')
    else:
        form = PasswordResetRequestForm()
    return render(request, 'front/reset_password_form.html', {'form': form})
```

If I check a few answers in Stackoverflow, i don't call the **form.is_valid()** method. I continue my search but my code worked yesterday but only when the user is connected. When the user forget his password, he is not able to connect with his session.

Sorry for my english, i don't speak it very well but i can give you more details if you want :)

Comment: Note that django.contrib.auth contains built-in functionality for password reset emails; you may want to use that instead of writing your own.

Comment: For some reasons i can't send in production my website with the django administration. I already used the functionality for reset emails but now i need to wirte my own.

Comment: I agree with Daniel, use the built-in password reset functionality if possible. The [django auth views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views) are separate from the Django admin. You can use them without the admin.

Comment: I will try it, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to access `cleaned_data` before calling `form.is_valid()`:

```
if User.objects.filter(email = form.cleaned_data['email']).exists() and form.is_valid():
```

I think you will get `cleaned_data` if you change the order:

```
if form.is_valid() and User.objects.filter(email = form.cleaned_data['email']).exists():
```

In the later case form is validated first and if it is valid you will have that data available in the second clause of the if condition.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but i have this answer now : 'unicode' object has no attribute 'email'